# Запятую сосем-совсем нечем оправдать?

Tags: пунктуация

> Посетить виллу архитектора Андреа Палладио, с росписями Веронезе
>   (вилла Барбаро в Мазере).

Контекст не нужен; это предложение - один из пунктов того, "что нам надо успеть за день".

Comment: Вилла Барбаро в посёлке Мазер (арх. Андреа Палладио) с росписями  Паоло Веронезе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая, как мне кажется, на месте.

Вилла может быть интересна во многих отношениях, но в данном случае важны  именно росписи Веронезе, **что особо подчеркивается.**

Хотя смысл  может быть разный: или у этого архитектора не одна вилла, или интерес вызывает преимущественно Веронезе.

Answer (score 0):

Запятую оправдать никак. Кроме того, что она не нужна формально, для тех, кто знает русский язык - она вносит некий элемент двусмысленности (намеком на перечисление): отдельно посещение виллы, отдельно - росписей может привидеться